# KnockoutJS - Comparing variables from parent and current context and set class

Tags: knockout.js

```
<!-- ko foreach: foos -->
<div>
    <div data-bind="text: name">
    ...
    <nav with: $root>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: foos">
            <!-- 
                I want <li> to  have class="active" if the "parent" name is the same as name in this context
                So something like
                    if $parents[1].name = name
            -->
            <li>
                 <a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    ...
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Is there a  way to this? Do I use KO's *if* keyword? Or am I just thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `$parent` variable to achieve what you want. For example:

```html
<li data-bind="css: { active: $parent.name() === name() }"></li>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYwHa/) to see this in action (assuming you've used observable properties) or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYwHa/1/) (if you use regular properties on your view model).

Have a look at the [Binding Context documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) and [CSS Binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) for more info.

Comment: Your code did not work. It did work for me when I used `$parents[1].name === name`. Any particular reason why `name` is called as a function?

Comment: You didn't provide any of your View Model code. In my example I assumed `name` would be declared as an observable (i.e. `this.name = ko.observable('john')`), which has to be called as a function to get the value. If you've declared it as a regular property (i.e. `this.name = 'john'`) then no parentheses would be needed. I've updated the answer.